# Windows Tar Command for Tape Drive

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, tar, tape

I am trying to generate a command using [GNUTar](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm) for backing up a folder on Windows 10 to a few tapes (hence my use of multisession). I am using an elevated command prompt window and have cd-ed into the GNUTar folder. Using Uranium Backup Pro: Tape, I have made sure that my tape system is fully functional and is not at fault.

When running the command `tar.exe -c --multi-volume -f "D:/Personal Media Archive" *` I receive a function not yet implemented error.

When I run `tar.exe -c --multi-volume -f "\Users\Steven\Downloads" *` I receive a permission denied error despite taking absolute ownership of the GnuWun32 folder (`C:\` removed based on [this Github Issue](https://github.com/benbaptist/minecraft-wrapper/issues/77)).

Can someone please advise me of the proper syntax for this command on Windows 10?